# Filling data into empty dataframe from other dataframes

Tags: pandas, python-3.5

I have an empty dataframe as:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

I have another dataframe as:

```
df1 = 

A           D   B
20181010    12  13
20181010    14  13
20181010    5   13
20181010    7   13
```

I want to fill df with data from df1 to get another dataframe as:

```
       A    B   C   D
20181010    13  NaN 12
20181010    13  NaN 14
20181010    13  NaN 5
20181010    13  NaN 7
```

`df1` is missing column C so it gets filled with NaN. Other versions of `df1` has other missing columns.

I am not sure how to populate `df` with data from `df1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `reindex`

```
df1.reindex(columns=df.columns)
Out[92]: 
          A   B   C   D
0  20181010  13 NaN  12
1  20181010  13 NaN  14
2  20181010  13 NaN   5
3  20181010  13 NaN   7
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case `pd.concat` will do:

```
df = pd.concat((df,df1))

>>> df
          A   B    C   D
0  20181010  13  NaN  12
1  20181010  13  NaN  14
2  20181010  13  NaN   5
3  20181010  13  NaN   7
```